# can not use ggplot in pycharm but spyder can

Tags: python, pycharm, python-ggplot

```
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd
y_name = 'y'
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4],y_name:[4,5,6,7]})
p =ggplot(df, aes(x='x', y='y'))+geom_point()
```

Then my PyCharm collapse, no photo and I have to restart python consol. But this code work in spyder.

Also when I do:

```
from ggplot import *
```

in `PyCharm`, it warns me that:

```
from ggplot import *
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ggplot\utils.py:81: FutureWarning: pandas.tslib is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
You can access Timestamp as pandas.Timestamp
  pd.tslib.Timestamp,
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py:20: FutureWarning: The pandas.lib module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. These are private functions and can be accessed from pandas._libs.lib instead
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py:20: FutureWarning: The pandas.core.datetools module is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use the pandas.tseries module instead.
  module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

this would not show up in spyder.

Comment: if i plot a picture using plotnine and show it. Pycharm would constantly pop the picture

Comment: You can try the [Lets Plot in SciView](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14379-lets-plot-in-sciview) PyCharm plugin.